# Separate simultaneously changing regions of video into individual videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, imagemagick

Given a single video stream (up to 4K resolution), where only small displayed portions may change, I'd like to identify these changing sections and create separate video streams, one for each changing section of the input video stream, in real time.

Note that this is spatial extraction, *not* time slicing!

Q1: Is there a better name to address this process?

Q2: Is this an already solved problem?

It seems ImageMagick's Compare program supports diffing two images, which I can process to identify regions as coordinates for an ffmpeg crop (launched in parallel for each discovered diff region), but this method relies on having a PNG stream to avoid false positive diffs due to lossy encoding. Also, too slow to happen in real time.

Q3: Is there any way ffmpeg can dump out the causal regions influencing scene-change detection?

Comment: Sounds like you need to upgrade from command line to programming. I recommend Java. Learn about bitmaps (how to: create one, check colours, etc). Use Java to control FFmpeg (travel frame by frame) by checking for differences over time. Then create a rectangular region around those coords and export as video.

Comment: Okay, I will approach this programmatically rather than as a pipeline of point-tools.